# @Click directive is calling the wrong event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

In my vue.js project I have multiple pages, between which I am navegating using a router. I have a page, on which there are some buttons doing some actions on the page and two buttons, which are used to navegate between pages. The first button (back button) is always visible, the second button (finish button) is only visible, if one of the otherbuttons is currently active.

Now, in the following situations I get the expected behavior:

- Not choosing any of the action buttons and clicking the back-button
- Choosing one ore multiple button and clicking the finish-button
- Choosing one or more buttons, deselecting them and clicking the back-button

In the last case, when selecting one or more buttons and then using the back-button, the button calls the event handler of the finish button (I figured this out because I used a debug statement in the event handlers).

I cannot make out the reason for this behaviour, help is appreciated.

Here are some parts of my code:

index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Page1 from '../views/Page1'
import Page2 from '../views/Page2'
import Page3 from '../views/Page3'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: {
        name: 'Page1'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/Page2',
    name: 'Page2',
    component: Page2
  },
  {
    path: '/Page3',
    name: 'Page3',
    component: Page3
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
})

export default router
```

Page1.vue

```
<template>
    <MultiButtons
        :titles = titles
        @toggle-button="toggle_button"
    />
    <BackButton
      @click.stop="$router.push({
        name: 'Page2'
      });;"
      text="Zurück"
    ></BackButton>
    <FinishButton
      @click.stop="$router.push({
        name: 'Page3', 
        params: 
          { chosenErrors: Array.from(this.activeButtons) }
      });"
      text="Fertig"
      :visible=ready
    ></FinishButton>
</template>

<script>

import MultiButtons from '../components/MultiButtons.vue'
import BackButton from "../components/BackButton.vue"
import Titles from "../assets/json/Beschreibungen_FehlerDokumentation.json"
import FinishButton from "../components/FinishButton.vue"

export default {
    name: 'Page1',
    props: {
    },
    components: {
        MultiButtons,
        BackButton,
        FinishButton
    },
    methods: {
      toggle_button(activeButtons){
        this.ready = (activeButtons.size != 0);
        this.activeButtons = activeButtons;
      }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            titles: Titles,
            ready: false,
            activeButtons: new Set([])
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

FinishButton.vue

```
<template>
    <div :style="visible ? { 'display': 'inline-flex' } : { 'display': 'none' }">
        <h3 class="descriptor">{{text}}</h3>
        <button/>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
 
    export default {
        name: 'FinishButton',
        props : {
            text: String,
            visible: Boolean
        }
    }

</script>
```

Backbutton.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button/>
        <h3 class="descriptor">{{text}}</h3>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
    
    export default {
        name: 'BackButton',
        props : {
            text: String
        }
    }

</script>
```

Multibuttons.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <MultiButton 
            v-for="(obj,index) in titles"
            :id=obj.id
            :title=obj.title
            @toggle-button="toggle_button"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import MultiButton from './MultiButton.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'MultiButtons',
        components : {
            MultiButton,
        },
        props : {
            titles: Array
        },        
        methods: {
            toggle_button(id) {
                this.activeButtons.has(id) ? this.activeButtons.delete(id) : this.activeButtons.add(id);
                this.$emit('toggle-button', this.activeButtons);
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                activeButtons: new Set([])
            }
        },
        emits:["toggle-button"]
    }

</script>
```

MultiButton.vue

```
<template>
        <button  
            @click.stop="toggle()">
            <h2 class="multibtn_title" :style="{ color: isActive ? 'white' : 'black'}">{{title}}</h2>
        </button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'MultiButton',
        props : {
            title: String,
            id: Number
        }, 
        data() {
            return {
                isActive: false
            }
        },    
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.isActive = !this.isActive;
                this.$emit('toggle-button', this.id);
            }
        },
        emits:["toggle-button"]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I threw your code into a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-wind-umuw6d?file=/src/views/Page1.vue) and didn't notice any errant behavior.  I only removed the FinishButton `visible` prop and display styling as it's much simpler to use `v-if`, but even before I made that change there were no bug as you described.  maybe it needs more of your code not shown to reproduce?  my only other idea is that some CSS gone wrong has you clicking an invisible FinishButton placed on top of the BackButton. With your original code try inspecting the DOM and confirm you're clicking the correct button.

Comment: Yes it was my error, it was a problem with the css styling. The div of the finish button span over the back button but was not being visible. Stupid, simple error.

Comment: @wittn, is this now solved? Maybe you can resolve your question?

Comment: @LeifMarcus yes, as I said above the problem was just with the css styling (which in did not include in my question). The divs of the two button were at the same height, not visible and stretched over 100% of the width. Therefore, when the finish button was not there, there was no problem; in the other case it would cover the back button, preventing it to be clicked and therefore not triggering it's event handler.